# Android drag and drop error

Tags: android, android-layout

I am following a step by step guide to mastering drag and drop and am frustrated that step 1 is giving me an error. I am getting a NoClassDefFoundError. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong.

It is really annoying that I copied the guys code exactly and it doesn't work.

I put a star on the line that it is crashing on. The one that defines clipdata.

> 07-01 14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-01 14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.content.ClipData 07-01
>   14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):    at
>   com.codelikely.tester.TestApplicationActivity.onTouch(TestApplicationActivity.java:29)
>   07-01 14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):  at
>   android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:4020) 07-01
>   14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869) 07-01
>   14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869) 07-01
>   14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869) 07-01
>   14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869) 07-01
>   14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1746)
>   07-01 14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1152)
>   07-01 14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):  at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2102) 07-01
>   14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1730)
>   07-01 14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):  at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2268) 07-01
>   14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):    at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1921) 07-01
>   14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-01
>   14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 07-01 14:37:47.544:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17055):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691) 07-01
>   14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-01
>   14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 07-01 14:37:47.544:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17055):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
>   07-01 14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665) 07-01
>   14:37:47.544: E/AndroidRuntime(17055):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            *ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");*
            View.DragShadowBuilder dsb = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(clipData, dsb, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using any external libraries?

Comment: No I am not. Just a regular starter application.

Comment: Which version of Android are you running on?

Comment: I am building for 4.03 and have a min SDK of 4. I am running it on my SGS2 which is 2.3.

Comment: Okay. But which version are you running the app on?

Comment: ClipData is only available from API level 11 and above. 2.3 is API 9.

Comment: Is there a workaround to be able to use ClipData for 10 and below?

Comment: Not an official one that I'm aware of. Or a non-official one.

Comment: Well that sucks...thanks for the response.

Comment: I've added a proper answer so that this question can be properly closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app cannot find the [ClipData](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.html) class. ClipDate is only available from API level 11 and above. You're running on 2.3, which is API level 9. As you are building against a higher API, you will not get an error at compile time. To make sure you aren't using any other classes added later on, try setting your project to build with 2.3, or whatever OS is your minimum target.